# How to specify a bold variant of a local font as a fallback in @font-face?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, fallback

I'd like to specify Arial Bold as the fallback font in a `@font-face` rule.
Like this:

```
@font-face {font-family: myCustomFont; src: url(http://unreachableHost/font1b.ttf), local(Arial Bold)}
```

But it doesn't work. At least not in Chrome. The fallback is not Arial Bold or even Arial Regular.

Here is an example with several font families.

```css
@font-face {font-family: mustBeArialBold; src: url(http://unreachableHost/font1b.ttf), local(Arial Bold)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeVerdanaBold; src: url(http://unreachableHost/font2b.ttf), local(Verdana Bold)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeSegoeBold; src: url(http://unreachableHost/font3b.ttf), local(Segoe UI Bold)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeTimesBold; src: url(http://unreachableHost/font4b.ttf), local(Times New Roman Bold)}
```

```html
<body style="text-align: right">

<b style="font-family: Arial">This is Arial Bold</b> <br>
<c style="font-family: mustBeArialBold">This should be Arial Bold</c> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Verdana">This is Verdana Bold</b> <br>
<c style="font-family: mustBeVerdanaBold">This should be Verdana Bold</c> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Segoe UI">This is Segoe UI Bold</b> <br>
<c style="font-family: mustBeSegoeBold">This should be Segoe UI Bold</c> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Times New Roman">This is Times New Roman Bold</b> <br>
<c style="font-family: mustBeTimesBold">This should be Times New Roman Bold</c> <br><br>
```

Is it possible to do this? How?

---

**FOLLOW UP:**

Here is the solution suggested by @Kerri

```css
@font-face {font-family: mustBeArial; src: local(Arial)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeVerdana; src: local(Verdana)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeSegoe; src:  local(Segoe UI)}

@font-face {font-family: mustBeTimes; src: local(Times New Roman)}
```

```html
<body style="text-align: right">

<b style="font-family: Arial">This is Arial Bold</b> <br>
<b style="font-family: mustBeArial">This should be Arial Bold</b> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Verdana">This is Verdana Bold</b> <br>
<b style="font-family: mustBeVerdana">This should be Verdana Bold</b> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Segoe UI">This is Segoe UI Bold</b> <br>
<b style="font-family: mustBeSegoe">This should be Segoe UI Bold</b> <br><br>

<b style="font-family: Times New Roman">This is Times New Roman Bold</b> <br>
<b style="font-family: mustBeTimes">This should be Times New Roman Bold</b> <br><br>
```

The resulting text is something that kind of looks like bold text but it's nothing like the true bold font.

Comment: You could try including a `font-weight: bold` property in your `@font-face` rule. See [MDN's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face), although I believe that would make your non-fallback font bold as well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a font called "Arial Bold" (I do have "Arial Black", though) on my computer, so the `local()` function isn't going to find an appropriate font to use. The display defaults to Times New Roman, as expected.

However, I do have Arial, so any call to plain old "Arial" works as expected.

In your code,

```
<b style="font-family: Arial">This is Arial Bold</b>
```

calls the font named Arial (which I've got), and since you've wrapped it in `b` tags, it's displaying as bold. So far so good.

But there's no such font as "Arial Bold" locally.

```
<c style="font-family: mustBeArialBold">This should be Arial Bold</c>
```

won't find a font called "Arial Bold" (because that doesn't exist on my computer), and since it's in a `c` element (what is that?) and not a `b` element, it's not going to display as bold. If you changed your `c` elements to `b` elements, your text would display as bold.

While you can try to add styling to your `@font-face` declarations, I tend to avoid doing font styling that way, and instead apply styles to classes. (A font face is a different thing than a font style, unless the styling is intentionally built into the font face by the developer of the font.) There's some good guidance here on how that works. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/setting-weights-and-styles-at-font-face-declaration/

Comment: It doesn't work either. The resulting text is some kind of faked bold font based on the regular font. It looks nothing like the true bold font. See the follow up in the question.

Comment: There's bold, and then there's bold, according to various browsers... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942625/font-face-bold-in-ff-is-bolder-than-in-chrome

Comment: The question is how to use the bold variant of a given font family. If you go to your ***Fonts*** system folder you'll find the `Arial` font file, the `Arial Bold` font file, the `Arial Italic` font file, and so on for each variant of that font family.